# Как создать папку в среде MS Windows XP с символом *(звёздочка)?

Tags: windows

Нужно создать в среде MS Windows XP папку, в имени которой содержится символ *(звёздочка)
Реально ли это? Друзья подсказали воспользоваться KNOPPIX(linux), создать так такую папку и перенести... Будет ли она тогда активной и сможет ли ссылаться на неё другая программа?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Одолевают меня сомнения, что это реально. Это один из служебных символов, я не представляю, как оно будет работать, например с поисковыми шаблонами (например *.*). А вот кодировка * может быть изменена, думаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Забавный результат.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main ()
{
  if (mkdir("*",0777))
    perror("mkdir");
}
```

Interix 3.5 gcc  - создает.
MinGW gcc - perror() печатает -   mkdir: Invalid argument.

Comment: Повторю -- это невозможно или приведет к постоянным крешам того же проводника при попытке обзора содержания папки, в которая будет находится эта "`*`".

Comment: Сразу на посмотрел, а как показывается это имя. Вот:

Interix (ksh): ls - \* т.е. в нем как создавали 'звездочку', так и показывает

Windows XP (cmd): dir - ? знак вопроса

MSYS MINGW32_NT-5.1 (bash): ls - ?  знак вопроса

emacs 23.2 (dired): a20f~1

Т.о. windows dll не принимает '\*' (видимо недопустимый символ).
Interix на что-то меняет ее, думаю на диске реально не '\*'.
Такие вот, интересные результаты. Видимо правильный ответ - НЕТ, создать имя '*' НЕЛЬЗЯ.

Comment: Проводник не падает, даже позволяет в ней файлы делать. Но имя '\*' не показывает. Кстати, cygwin это оглавление видит, как '?', но работать с ним решительно не хочет.

Comment: А Вы посмотрите самописной утилитой через Native API настоящее имя файла. Почти наверняка оно будет юникодовское.

Comment: >Повторю -- это невозможно или приведет к постоянным крешам того же проводника при попытке обзора содержания папки, в которая будет находится эта "*".

Мне не столько надо обзор папки...мне нужно чтобы программа записывала в неё данные...креш проводника? как это выражается и серъёзная ли это проблема? Это реально? создать в линаксе и перенести чтобы прога туда записывала информацию?(забыв про последстыия и возможные проблемы)

Answer (score 1):

Это возможно только на уровне драйвера (обманкой), но это приведет к ошибкам доступа и вообще испортит диск.

"*" используется как match-выражение подразуемевающее <что угодно> (кстати).
Также, например, невозможно создать (на WinXP) папку с именем "COS", если я не ошибаюсь. Но это вроде уже пасхалка сделанная специально...

P.S: нет, это нереально. И кстати, символ "*" почти во всех кодировка собой останется, если я прав, конечно.

Comment: "con" - потому, что это устройство, но корни те же

Comment: Дело в том что, что при поиске ответа на мой вопрос я нашёл как создатьCON: mkdir \\.\“путь”\“имя_папки”.    Например: mkdir \\.\C:\con, Но также папку * создавать нехочет, НО я увидел вот такой коммент на форуме: Кстати, ещё можно сделать такую папку, если смонтировать жесткий диск из Линукса (его запустить с другого жесткого диска, или с Live CD). Линукс ничего не имеет против папок с именем “con”. :)! Также способ создания :
Пишет "СО" - русские, "N" - английское. Потом "переименовать" и меняем СО на английскок CO.
пашет...я думал может и с недопустимыми символами есть како-то способ...

Comment: con создать как раз можно. Просто con - это у-во для DOS command prompt, поэтому и обрабатывается спец. образом. А вот с звездочкой - точно никак не сделать.